# creating a shopping cart using php and sql

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a shopping cart system for estore on my website but I'm having trouble getting anything to work.   I started out by creating a file to display my products from the database but they aren't showing up.  Its supposed to display the name, price, and description for each product but it just says name, price, and description instead of the actual information.  Here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('config.php');
$itemCount = 0;

if(isset($_SESSION['cart']));

$itemCount= count (isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array()    );
 }
     ?>

  <html>

 <head>

 </head>

 <ul>
   <li><a href="index1.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="cart1.php">View cart</a></li>
    <li> { <?php echo $itemCount; ?>  }  </li>

   </ul>


    <p class= "msg">

    <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) {
        switch($_REQUEST['msg']):

        case 'add':

            $msg = $_REQUEST['p'] . " was added to your cart.";

        break;

        endswitch;

        echo $msg;

   }
    ?>

    <h2>Products</h2>
     <ul>
     <li>Name</li>
     <li>Price</li>
    <li>Description</li>
     </ul>



    <?php 

    $prod =mysql_query($db, "SELECT * FROM 'Products' ");


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($db)){
    extract($r);

    ?>

    <div>

   <div class="inline-pr"><?=$productName?></div>
   <div class="inline-pr"><?=$price?></div>

</div>

</body
</html>
```

Comment: You might simplify and reword this question. "How do I select data from a database and loop through it for display?" The PHP docs have a lot of simple examples to follow in the user notes. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Do you get any error? Might be worth checking out the logs...